# OnLocationChanged() Exception

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, location-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have developed an application using the Fused location provider. In the `onConnected()` method, I am requesting for location updates and the application logic will be initiated  and `onLocationChanged()` is called.

**Problem** : `onLocationChanged()` method is not called in devices in US . This code works perfectly fine on devices in INDIA but does not work on US. By does not work, I mean that `locationClient` gets connected but `onLocationChanged()` is never called.

**Code Below:**

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
        implements
        // GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        // GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    // LocationClient locationclient = null;
    GoogleApiClient locationclient = null;
    Context contxt;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        contxt = context;
        // Log.i("locationreciever", "in location rec");,
        Log.i("fused", "in location rec");

        int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

        if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            // locationclient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
            locationclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)// (mConnectionCallbacks)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)// (mOnConnectionFailedListener)
                    .build();
            locationclient.connect();
        } else {
            Log.i("fused", "loc client Google Play Service Error");
        }
    }

    public void updateTransientLocation(Context context, Location loc) {
        // Log.i("updateTransientLocation", "in fn");

        float lat = (float) loc.getLatitude();
        float lon = (float) loc.getLongitude();
        float acc =  loc.getAccuracy();
        float alt = (float) loc.getAltitude();

        if (lat > 0 && lon > 0) {
            PreferenceForApp prefs = new PreferenceForApp(contxt);
            prefs.setTransientLatitude(lat);
            prefs.setTransientLongitude(lon);
            prefs.setTransientAccuracy(acc);
            prefs.setTransientAltitude(alt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("fused",
                " onLocationChanged Location Request :"
                        + location.getLatitude() + ","
                        + location.getLongitude() + " acc "
                        + location.getAccuracy()+" alt "+location.getAltitude());
        //TODO wait for some time to get location
        updateTransientLocation(contxt, location);
        if (locationclient != null) {
            if (locationclient.isConnected()) {
                // locationclient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                        locationclient, this);

                locationclient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        PreferenceForApp prefs = new PreferenceForApp(contxt);
//      if (arg0.hasResolution()) {
//          try {
//              // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
//              arg0.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
//          } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }}else{
        Log.i("fused", "loc client connection failed");
        prefs.setGooglePlayServiceErrorCode(arg0.getErrorCode());
    }
//}

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        PreferenceForApp prefs = new PreferenceForApp(contxt);
        prefs.setGooglePlayServiceErrorCode(0);
        Log.i("fused", "loc client onConnected");
        LocationRequest locationrequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationrequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

//      PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        // locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationclient, locationrequest, this); // mLocationListener);
    }

    // @Override
    // public void onDisconnected() {
    // Log.i("fused", "loc client disconnected");
    // }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        Log.i("fused", "loc client onConnectionSuspended");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the fact that the phone can't connect with the service provider?

try using the gps.

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
// Or, use GPS location data:
// String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

Comment: how can i use location Manager in FusedLocationApi ,? By using FusedLocation I am already getting location updated by GPS

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using NETWORK_PROVIDER to access/get the location update.

Try to use **GPS_PROVIDER** or use **PASSIVE_PROVIDER** to get location from either NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER.

Make sure you have permission in manifest to access NETWORK and GPS locations.

Comment: but i am using FusedLocationApi and it works on All (GPS_provider , Network_provider) .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FusedLocationProviderApi`, you have the option of using the `SettingsApi` to check if a device has the location settings required by an application. The `SettingsApi` and optionally provides a location dialog to update the device's location settings if they are found to be inadequate. You can look at an [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationSettings). Run the sample with the location turned off in `Settings`, and you should see the dialog. Your app may be failing because it doesn't have sufficient permissions, and the location dialog could help.